# Is there a way to delete a Google Spreadsheet in .net using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-api

I have a .net6 web application where I can create a Google Spreadsheet from a template and retrieve data from this spreadsheet, but now I need to delete this Spreadsheet.

I am doing all this with the SheetService, but I could not find in the package as well as in the Google "documentation" an option to delete the whole Spreadsheet.

Is there a way to do that or I have to use an HttpRequest for it as stated here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#delete-sheet

I did not try the HttpRequest approach yet, because I kind of know this would work (I used it to retrieve tokens and other operations), but I would like to do that with SheetsService.

Answer (score 0):

@fernando-silva To delete a sheet within a worksheet using the Google v4 API, try the following code.

```
// Check if the sheet exists
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var spreadsheetId = "--google--spreadsheet--identifier";
var request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
var response = request.Execute();

var sheet = response.Sheets.FirstOrDefault(sheet => sheet.Properties.Title.Equals(sheetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

if (sheet != null) 
{
    service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest
    { 
        Requests = new Request[]
        { 
            new Request()
            { 
                DeleteSheet = new DeleteSheetRequest { SheetId = sheet.Properties.SheetId }
            }
        }
    }, spreadsheetId).Execute();
}
```